# ASP.NET Core 7 valditate IAsyncEnumerable against data annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, iasyncenumerable, asp.net-core-7.0

How to perform a data annotation validation for the input as IAsyncEnumerable in ASP.NET Core 7 API controller POST action. I tried to use the following code, but validation didn't occur.

```cs
public record struct Car([Required][RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{8}$")] string? Number);

public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("cars")]
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<Car> PostCarsAsync([FromBody] IAsyncEnumerable<Car> cars, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        await foreach (var car in cars)
        {
            yield return car;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to pass the following request

> [{},{"Number":""},{"Number":"87654321"}]

and got the following response without any validation errors:

> [{"Number":null},{"Number":""},{"Number":"87654321"}]

So, the validation of input sequence didn't work.

Comment: Why `[FromBody] IAsyncEnumerable<Car>`? There's no infinite stream of cars in a POST request.

Comment: A `string?` can't be required. It explicitly says it's OK to be `null`. If you *don't* want null numbers, use `string Number`. I think you need to use `[property:RegularExpression]` and `[property:Required]` too, otherwise the attribute applies only to the constructor argument, not the property

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I don't want to buffer long inputs. I'm going to process input items one by one without extra memory pressure

Comment: The input comes from the client with the HTTP POST body, you have no control over it. Besides, `IEnumerable` already accesses the input one item at a time. `IAsyncEnumerable` is used to allow asynchronous iteration, something that's *not* needed here

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to fix your `Car` record by retargeting attributes to property (and possibly removing the `Required` one and changing the `Number` to be a non-nullable string):

```cs
public record struct Car([property: RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{8}$")] string Number);
// or
public record struct Car([property: Required][property: RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{8}$")] string? Number);
```

Secondary I would argue that this concrete case is conceptually impossible - you need to buffer the whole input (or output) to validate before starting to process it - imagine that you have invalid record at the end of the list - `yield return car;` should already have started writing to output correct records so what should happen here? And even if you are not returning async enumerable from your method I would say that non-buffering validation is still impossible in the standard ASP.NET Core pipeline (because binding and validation should finish before the action itself). So you need to switch to `IEnumerable` if you need build-in validation:

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Car> PostCarsAsync([FromBody] IEnumerable<Car> cars, CancellationToken ct)
{
    // ...
}
```

Also [this open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43489) hints that possibly `IAsynEnumerable` should have no effect on buffering (though in my tests with .NET 7 switching to `IAsynEnumerable` had some effect on memory patterns, at least at first glance).